# Set img src with file

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, file

I have a Vue application with an .NET backend. In my application I have items that can be uploaded. When I upload an image the file is saved on my backend and the file location is send to the db. When I click an item on my page I do a get request to the server with the file path and the endpoint returns an image. I want this image data set as the src of my <img>.

I tried setting the src with the data of the result aswell as base64 encoded image.

I have this method:

```
async getPhotoLocation(photoLocation) {
  try {
    const response = await GetPhotoByPath(photoLocation);
    if (response && response.status === 200) {
      return `data:${response.headers["content-type"]};base64,${response.data}`;
    } else {
      console.error("Failed to retrieve image:", response);
      return "path/to/default/image.jpg";
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error retrieving image:", error.message);
    return "path/to/default/image.jpg";
  }
},
```

This method is called in the src of my image like this:

```
<img v-if="selectedItem" :src="getPhotoLocation(selectedItem.photoLocation)" alt="Oops! No image was found!" />
```

And this is the function in my api.js file:

```
export const GetPhotoByPath = async (path) => {
  const token = getToken();

  if (token) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };

    try {
      const response = await api.get(
        "/v1/Photo/getByPath?filePath=" + path,
        config
      );

      if (response.status === 200) {
        return response;
      } else {
        console.error("Unexpected status code:", response.status);
        return false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading image:", error.message);
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    clearStorage();
    console.error("Token not available. Redirecting to login...");
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the URL of the image from `selectedItem.photoLocation`? I don't really understand what you're trying to do here

Comment: @Lucas The place where I want to show the picture is on the frontend website and the backend, the place where the image is stored is on another server so the image location is not present on the page.

Comment: Ok I see. But still, if your backend service serves an image as response, you should be able to use this backend service URL  directly in your img src, assuming you return the correct Content-Type header along with the response (which depends on the image type)

Comment: @Lucas I don't get it to work...